# Wordpress Options Page not working

Tags: wp-admin, options

So, I need to add a custom options page, and based on as many tutorials I could find, I came up with the following code to create an officers & chairs options page for my group, mainly, so I can write more advanced stuff for my site. The code is here:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'composit_settings_page');

function composit_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page('Officers & Chairs', 'Officers & Chairs', 'manage_options', 'officers_chairs', 'composit_settings');
}

function composit_settings()
{
    $actives = get_users('role=contributor');
    $actives = array_merge($actives, get_users('role=editor'));
    $actives = array_merge($actives, get_users('role=administrator'));


$positions = array(
    "prytanis",
    "epiprytanis",
    "hypophetes",
    "hegemon",
    "grammateus",
    "histor",
    "pylortes",
    "crysopholos"
);

?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
        <h2>Officers & Chairs</h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('officers-chairs'); ?>
            <?php foreach($positions as $position):
                    register_setting('officers-chairs', $position, 'intval');
                  endforeach; ?>
            <table class="form-table">
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($positions as $position): ?>
                        <tr valign="top">
                            <th scope="row">
                                <label for="<?= $position ?>"><?= ucwords($position) ?></label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <select name="<?= $position ?>" id="<?= $position ?>" class="regular-text">
                                    <?php foreach($actives as $active): ?>
                                        <option value="<?= $active->ID ?>" <?php if(get_option($position) == $active->ID) { ?> selected <? } ?>><?=$active->first_name . " " . $active->last_name ?></option>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Save Changes"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
<?
}
```

However, when I go to save that, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: options page not found.
```

I feel completely dumb for not being able to figure this out, but the official documentation hasn't really helped me at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem part is this line:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

This sends your form to **wp-admin/options.php** (and I guess you're not sending the form from this URL). Leave the action value empty like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

And your form will send itself to the same page from which it was sent. Then you can save the settings accessing $_POST variable before outputing

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">...
```

Hope this helps...

PS: you should also consider using wordpress nonces. Eg. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field

Comment: Save settings before output? Know the function off hand?And there is a wpnonce field in there once the page actually outputs.

update_option(). We'll see if this works.

Comment: Not sure I understand this answer. The options page is defined by a function. You have to run through validation before saving and the saving should be a separate function.